# How to copy the whole line with easy way in emacs?

Tags: emacs

to copy the whole line, I use :

```
ctrl+k
and ctrl+y (restore the kill line)
and use ctrl+y to yank it
```

is there any easy way?

Comment: Visual line (e.g., wrapped at the window edge -- left edge of the window to right edge of the window), or from point at beginning of line to point at ending of line (regardless of whether the line is wrapped at the window edge)?

Comment: visual is more steps.

Comment: For a non-visual-line solution, how about using the built-in function `copy-line`?  `M-x describe-function RET copy-line RET`  If you use `visual-line-mode` and need more help beyond `copy-line`, post another comment please.

Comment: @lawlist: Where do you see a built-in `copy-line` command? I don't see that, using `emacs -Q`. There are several versions of such a command [on the wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyingWholeLines), but I don't see one built in.

Comment: @Drew -- thank you -- you are absolutely correct -- I must have added it to my user configuration some time ago and just forgotten that it was there.  I probably got it from wiki.

Comment: @Drew great work.

Comment: There is a package named `whole-line-or-region` (https://github.com/purcell/whole-line-or-region). I haven't tried it myself, but if it works like I think is does then you can simply do `M-w` (assuming that the region is not active).